# Python 2.7.1 - How to document method argument type?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have read [PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). But it does not say anything on how to specify the type of a function argument.

Is the below one recommended -

```
def decrypt_and_verify_bundle(bundle_file):
    """
    Decrypts and verifies a bundle
    :param bundle_file: string
        absolute path to the bundle file
    :return: string
        tar file present in the bundle
    """
```

Comment: There are many styles, see e.g. http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html, http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_numpy.html#example-numpy

Comment: You might also want to check [PEP 484 - Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). Although a Python 3.5+ feature, it has a [special section for Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#id50). Also, [stub files](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files) can be used with Python 2.7.

Comment: @shmee - One question after reading 2.7 section in the link you shared. If I have a method with signature like `def run_local_cmd(cmd, raise_exception=True, console_print=True, use_shell=True)`. Based on the value of `use_shell` `cmd` can be `string` or `list`. I know this is not a good practice. But can you let me know what is the recommended way to capture this in the `#type` docstring?

Comment: Assuming it's a list of strings: `Union[str, List[str]]`. But you could also use `Union[str, list]` if the content of the list is arbitrary. `Union[str, List]` should work as well.

Comment: @shmee - Can you post your comments as answer as I am using the ones you mentioned in your comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#suggested-syntax-for-python-2-7-and-straddling-code) suggests the following syntax for Python 2.7 (Note, since you don't mention the return type of your run_local function, I am assuming `None` here):

```
def run_local(cmd, raise_exception=True, console_print=True, use_shell=True):
    # type: (Union[str, List[str]], bool, bool, bool) -> None
```